# How to add a breed to an animal from the available breeds in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am looking how i can assign a breed to an animal upon the creation of an animal for example i have added many breeds to my database and now i want to clean it and assign a breed to each animal for example dogs can have rottweiler, Abradore and more in the rest framework this is how I made my serializer but it makes me create a new breed each time instead of chosing the breed from the available breeds

```
class AnimalBreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AnimalBreed
        fields = ("name",)


class AnimalTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    animal_breed = AnimalBreedSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AnimalBreed
        fields = ("name","animal_breed")
```

these are my models

```
class AnimalBreed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True, primary_key=True)


class AnimalType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(AnimalBreed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in admin? If you have created instances of AnimalBreed, then with this model layout, you should be able to select AnimalBreed in breed when creating a new instance of AnimalType

Comment: i haven't set the permissions yet but yes it should be only the admin that is able to create new breeds and new animals and assign each breed to the animal.. but i am trying to implement the logic before getting the permissions into this.. as i said i ended up creating a new breed each time i create an animal and try to assign a breed to it.. idk but i started to have the doubts that my model is kind wrong and i need to reverse it.. aka getting the animal type in breed not the breed in animal type.. what do you think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this by changing the models and serializers with the appropriate fields.